# Use of JWT Token in open source project

Tags: audit, jwt, code-review

I'm currently performing a code audit for an application that a company will release to the public as open-source in the next few days.

In this application, they use a JWT token for authentication and on the backend, you can clearly see the secret that the JWT is using. This could be dangerous, right?

For example, if someone uses this application with the default config and doesn't change the secret?

Comment: Yes, just leave it empty and tell the user to configure a secret

Comment: Did you mean "on the backend" or "in the code" ?

Comment: on the backend!